# Cut off the broken sector while preserving data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ntfs

I have 320GB drive with following layout:
100 MB - win data; 100 GB win partition (boot+data); 190GB data; 30 GB Linux

Now my system started to hang up, I got many atapi errors and some ntfs errors, in windows error log. So I ran some disk inspector software and found that on sector around 3GB in is corrupted. The smart data also show warnings for sector relocations. I ran chkdsk and it was able to repair some damage.

Now my idea before buying new HDD is to cut off the first few gigabytes and left is unassigned. But the corrupt sector is on bootable partition in the left part.

Can you point to some software capable of cutting off the left part while preserving data and boot capabilities?

I know about GParted and Acronis Disc director, but I have no idea if this is possible.

PS: I'm aware that the disk is probably heading to silicon heaven, so this is only temporary solution. But I need to run the PC for at least few weeks before I will be able to get new HDD.

Comment: You want to backup anything important *first*

Comment: Already done, I backup to cloud regularly.

Comment: What you want won't be possible.  The reason your system stopped booting is because the bad sectors, contained those files, you were able to repair the damage for now.  The best solution is create an image of the hdd and ignore all errors, this will allow you to replace the hdd, and restore the hdd if you so desire.

Comment: No so sure about this but you can try Partition Wizard (Free). You can download the bootable .iso or the bootable flash drive installer. The idea is not to simply cut the left side but to resize (shrink) a partition by the size you want unallocated and move the adjacent partitions to the right until you have the unallocated space on the leftmost part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern filesystems like NTFS have "bad block" features, in which any sector known to be unuseable will be avoided. All you need to do is run chkdsk with the /r parameter, and your Drive letter (for example, `chkdsk /r C:`). I'm sure you can do something similar with your Linux-based O/S, but I can't say for sure without knowing what filesystem you're using (knowing which system might help, too).

Also, there is a program called **DRevitalize**, which can permanently repair damaged HDD sectors. Do note that the files that once occupied those sectors will likely be (irreversibly) corrupt, although they can be deleted, allowing you to reuse that space. DRevitalize doesn't know or care what filesystem you have, since it focuses only on individual sectors, and not on actual data, os it doesn't matter if you use FAT, NTFS, Ext, BTRFS, etc. Because of this, you should probably run a filesystem error checker (such as chkdsk or fsck) before **and** after using it. DRevitalize has a Windows version and a DOS version (which can be used on a bootable DOS floppy to repair unbootable machines).

Comment: I'm on Win7, NTFS. I ran `chkdsk /f`, but didn't help much.

Comment: @jnovacho - That **isn't** the command that was suggested.

Comment: Indeed, altough `chkdsk /f` can fix some problem, the /x parameter is necessary to find out which sectors are bad. Otherwise, the operation might end up being a waste of time.

Comment: I just realized I meant to say the /r parameter is necessary, __not__ /x. my bad.